# How to add commas and 3 trailing zeros to a column in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R that contains a column called AverageSalary with just numbers that vary in length from 1-4 integers. I want to add 3 0's to the end of the number regardless of length and add a comma for every 3 integers.

I have tried a concatenation and `sprintf` (gives me leading zeros). Does anybody have any ideas?

```
Average Salary Desired Format
             3          3,000
           144        144,000
          5678      5,678,000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `formatC`.

```
x <- c(3, 144, 5678)

formatC(x*1e3, format='f', digits=0, big.mark=',')
# [1] "3,000"     "144,000"   "5,678,000"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `scales::comma()`:

```
library(scales)

comma(AverageSalary * 1000)
# "3,000"     "144,000"   "5,678,000"
```